# Contextual filter from Taxonomy inside a paragraph

Tags: views, paragraphs

I have content-type (Destination) with a paragraph added as a component. This paragraph has a referenced taxonomy vocabulary (location). I want to display a list of nodes from another content-type (Blogs) filtered by location.

I created a custom template for this paragraph and I want to send the taxonomy term as an argument to a view. In my twig template and using twig_tweaks, I set the location id as follow:`{% set location = content.field_my_location[0]['#plain_text'] %}` and I display the view with  `{{ drupal_view('my_view', 'my_view_display', location) }}`.

The view displays when the contextual filter is set to display all results. I do not know how to filter by location.

I added my field that contains the paragraph as a relationship (field_components), then I added the location field (field_my_location) as a contextual filter. It does not work and I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to solve this by adding three relationship.

The first relationship is my blog location taxonomy term field "field_blog_location".

The second relationship I added is a referenced taxonomy term to the location field in the paragraph "Paragraph using field_my_location" This relationship is required.

The third relationship to add is the bridge to the Content entity that is referencing Taxonomy term via field_my_location_field_on_the_paragraph'. You set it up to use the second relationship as its relationship.

Last, you set up a contextual filter on field_my_location using the third relationship.

Hope it helps someone!